# Heroku "npm run build" fails in svg processing

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Rails+React(CRA) application to Heroku, but it's failing during npm build process. Seems like some issue related to svg processing, but I have no clues on what it is since it's my first deployment to Heroku using svgs in React.

This project does not use TS, maybe this could be somehow related to the issue (unlikely).

```
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:
remote:        ./src/icons/bathtub.svg (./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib?-prettier,-svgo!./src/icons/bathtub.svg)
remote:        /tmp/build_82ed3f6cbde426f6c9dc61dd68d32e7c/frontend/node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib/index.js:35
remote:          const pBabelTransform = async jsCode => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
remote:                                        ^^^^^^
remote:        SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
remote:
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.8.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-devise": "0.0.19",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.1.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: @MaviDomates packages.json added

Comment: What's the local node version you're using - node -v?

Comment: Turns out it was really a problem with node version. My local version was 11.4.0 and I think Heroku's was 6.x.x. I updated my parent's project package.json to use the same version as my local and it worked.